# Can I make the configuration for the analysis in php? on codeQL

Tags: php, github, codeql

I have this error, I read that it can be configured to scan php code, but it fails. What am I doing wrong?

Languages from configuration: php
Error: Did not recognize the following languages: php

name: "CodeQL"

on:
push:
branches: [ "main" ]
pull_request:
# The branches below must be a subset of the branches above
branches: [ "main" ]
schedule:
- cron: '21 0 * * 4'

jobs:
analyze:
name: Analyze

```
runs-on: ${{ (matrix.language == 'swift' && 'macos-latest') || 'ubuntu-latest' }}
timeout-minutes: ${{ (matrix.language == 'swift' && 120) || 360 }}
permissions:
  actions: read
  contents: read
  security-events: write

strategy:
  fail-fast: false
  matrix:
    language: [ 'javascript-typescript' ]

steps:
- name: Checkout repository
  uses: actions/checkout@v3

# Initializes the CodeQL tools for scanning.
- name: Initialize CodeQL
  uses: github/codeql-action/init@v2
  with:
    languages: php
```

actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun

below for guidance.

```
- name: Perform CodeQL Analysis
  uses: github/codeql-action/analyze@v2
  with:
    category: "/language:${{matrix.language}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

CodeQL does not support PHP at the moment, see [Supported languages and frameworks](https://codeql.github.com/docs/codeql-overview/supported-languages-and-frameworks/) and [this question asking for PHP support](https://github.com/github/codeql/issues/12376).

However, you can set up other tools for GitHub Code Scanning which support PHP. Some examples are:

- [Psalm](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/psalm-static-analysis-for-php)
- [PHPMD](https://phpmd.org/documentation/ci-integration.html#github-actions)
- ...

(I am not familiar with PHP development, so I cannot say how good these tools listed above are, and if there are better alternatives.)

In your GitHub repository, when you go to "Settings" > "Code security and analysis" > "Code scanning" > "Other tools", "Explore workflows" you can see more code scanning tools (not all of them support PHP though).